# Is the integration of instagram and Watson Assistant possible?

Tags: instagram, integration, chatbot, ibm-watson

I recently did some Watson Assistant integrations. Whatsapp, Telegram and Facebook Messenger and now I'm looking to do the same thing with Instagram.

I saw that Facebook (now Meta) recently published the API to do this integration. But I tried to replicate what I had done on Facebook Messenger, (set up webhoock, link page, set up test user) and Direct doesn't give me a return.

I would like to know if Watson and this API are compatible with each other.

And if not, is there any platform to do this integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently possible.

Instagram provides an API in which you can capture a Webhook and exchange messages, while node red creates a url that will be sent and received as responses

Comment: How would you do it, will developers.facebook.com allow this ?

Comment: Yup. It turns out that when you create an instance of a watson assistant it has some integration options natively, you can configure the facebook messenger integration that will generate a WEBHOOK and an integration token. On facebook for devs, there is an option that needs to be enabled for you to connect these services (messenger in the main panel). once enabled, it will generate a new tab of options to configure the bot on both facebook and instagram, generating the bot token and linking the url of the WEBHOOK generated in ibm and the integration token.

Comment: The issue is that at the moment there is no Watson integration with instagram

Answer (score 0):

You can also use captivate hub to connect your watson assistant on instagram

Link: https://hub.captivat.io

Manual: https://manual.captivat.io/install/channels/instagram